# Dropdown Menu closed when we click all place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have the following scripts in my dropdown menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $("#nav > li > a").click(function () { // binding onclick
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
            $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");

            if ($(this).next(".subs").length) {
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); // display popup
                $(this).next(".subs").children().slideDown(200);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
<span>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Produk Teknik <i class='icons icon-right-dir'></i></a>
            <div class="subs">
                <div class="wrp3">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h3>Manometer</h3>
                            <ul>
                               <li><a href='#'>tes</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href='#' class='anak'>tes-1</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><br /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

I need to change that script so that when we click all place, the dropdown menu will automatically be closed. Thank you

You can see my project example http://www.tokobesi.co.id/beta/

Comment: could u provide your html..

Comment: what does class `selected` do..??It would be lot easier if u could make a fiddle mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you meant mate..Try this.. :)

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if( $(e.target).closest(".menu").length > 0 ) {
        return false;
    }else{
        $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
    }
});
```